# How to define a singleton method readonly for method of an instance in rails 3.2.12?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, singleton

In our rails 3.2.12 app, we want to inject a method readonly to the method of an `instance` to mark a column as `readonly` or not. Ideally we can define ONE generic method `readonly` for all method of an `instance` of each and every `model` in the app.

For example, `@project` is an instance of the `Project model`. There is an `phone#` in the `@project`. After method injection, we can evaluate `@project.phone.readonly` (true or false) at run time. If there is another model `customer` in the app, we can do `@customer.name.readonly` assuming `@customer` is an `instance` of the `customer`.

We feel `singleton class` and `define_method` may help here. But we are not quite understand how they are going to work. Can someone shed some light on the issue? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user938363 If you need to define a method *once* and call it from any *instance* then you should be defining the method in the *Class*, not in the singleton instance.

```
class Float
  def readonly?
    true
  end
end

n = 1.234
n.readonly? # => true
```

Comment: That is not instance method, but class method... readonly? == true for all floats

Answer (score 1):

http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/define_singleton_method read this

But I think it's  bad idea, because some of your attributes(phone,name, etc) can be one of immutable or frozen  objects, so it will cause TypeError

Example

```
 1.9.3p125 :001 > number = 5.34
     => 5.34 
    1.9.3p125 :002 > def number.readonly?
    1.9.3p125 :003?>   true
    1.9.3p125 :004?>   end
    TypeError: can't define singleton method "readonly?" for Float
```

I would suggest you to think about some kind of next interface

```
@project.readonly?(:name)
```

Also check this
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ReadonlyAttributes/ClassMethods/attr_readonly 
 https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/readonly_attributes.

It allows you to do something like this  in your initializer

```
class  ActiveRecord::Base
  def attr_readonly?(attr_name)
     self.class.readonly_attributes.include(attr_name)
  end
end
```

and then

```
 class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_readonly :phone
 end
```

If don't need  attr_readonly functionallity, that doesn't allow to change readonly attributes after object was created, you can create your own module like this but with another class_attribute variable.

Comment: immutable or frozen would be problem. Are objects of some data type (as float and integer) immutable or fronzen by nature? @project.readonly?(:phone) would be OK in our app. Is there a way we can define it once and call from any instance?

Comment: yes they immutable by nature, also they are frozen from ruby 2.0